# How to get Column header value of selected row in gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this code

```
protected void btn_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 int Index = ((GridViewRow)((sender as Control)).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        Response.Write("btn_Check_Click event called" + Index.ToString());
}
```

in which each cell of the gridview is having a button.
Please tell how to get the column value of the selected row in this.
here Index of each cell is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the cell (column) index you can use something like `yourGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text`.